# Fragment Transaction In a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragmenttransaction

I have been building an social media app recently and faced a strange problem. I have a RecyclerView with items like this    :

[image]

Here the gray part is A FrameLayout.The Problem is about that FrameLayout actually. The problem is that when I try to transact a childFragment to it it only transacts into the first item and other items in recyclerview is left empty.
the adapter is like this

[image]

To make the things clear, when I submit a list like (ContentType.Video,ContentType.Gallery,ContentType.Image) it shows only ImageContent fragment inside of the first item of the RecyclerView. In my opinion this is something about the "id" part but I did not manage to solve this problem.
Does anyone have a solition for this ?

Comment: Can you avoid using fragments in your RecyclerView? I don't think that's a valid use case for fragments, you should use custom layouts instead.

Comment: this is the the first solution to my case that comes to my mind actually, the posts have same basic structure and they just differ at the content , there will be posts with text+image, text+video etc. Better idea about this @npace

Comment: yes you can you multiple view in recyclerView the one view with text+image and the second one text+Video its simple avoide using fragment into recyclerView

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-multiple-view-types-in-android

Comment: Yeah, look for some tutorials about "custom layout" or "compound controls", here's a nice starting point: https://medium.com/@tinnova/building-a-reusable-custom-layout-in-android-6fd2d977bfa0